# How do I run react source code in the local

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been cloned React's code from github，and I want to run code in the local to learn React.But I got wrong whith `Unsupported URL Type "link:": link:./scripts/eslint-rules/` when I execute `npm install`。

node versions in v8.11.0
npm versions in v5.6.0

Hope to have god to guide the maze！

Answer (score 1):

Best is to setup a build process with npm. It requires babel to transform jsx into js.

But for the beginning, you can load reactjs and babel in browser to get going.  All the info is available in getting started documentation page Getting Started | React.

Comment: thank you for your answer，I don't know if there is something wrong with my presentation, because my English is really not very good. 
 I'm not going to build React's application，I want to run source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command in project directory:

```
yarn add build
```

and then write:

```
yarn start
```